# functions in list loop not running one by one in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, loops

i have 5+ functions, so i want to run all functions one by one in series. like if i put loop range = 10 and i have 5 functions on list, so func1() should run once and func2() on 2nd and func3() on 3rd range and it should be in loop until range = 10 reaches.

```
    loop = 10
    funcs = [func1(), func2(), func3(), func4(), func5()]

    for i in range(funcs,loop):
        print(i)
```

i have tried this way but if the loop range is 10 then each functions running 10 times, thats what this loop should not act like that. it should work like if loop range is 10 and i have 5 funtions then each function should run once until loop range reaches.

Comment: you have to understand that range works in following manner. `range(start, stop[, step])`

Answer (score 3):

Functions are called when you put `()` after the name. You need to take the `()` out of the list, and put it into the loop.

Also, `funcs` is not a valid argument to `range()`, it only takes numbers. Use `i` to get the index into `funcs`.

```
loop = 10
funcs = [func1, func2, func3, func4, func5]
mobile_number = '123-456-7890'
amount = 50

for i in range(loop):
    print(funcs[i % len(funcs)](mobile_number, amount))
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/YIOgPD)

Comment: still working same as i posted, still repiting each function 10 times, each function should run once.

Comment: i have some functions like - oxigenwallet(mobile_number,amount) , decathlon(mobile_number,amount),  i want to run each fucnctions one my one in a loop by a range.

Comment: Just put the arguments in the parentheses in the loop: `funcs[i % len(funcs)](mobile_number, amount)`

Comment: please give a example. THANK YOU.

Comment: :/ still same thing happening, each fuction repting 10 times then going to next function.
it should work like 1 function run once then should go to other function.

Comment: thankx for your help. actually i am using selenium, and the each functions are a websites automation, each function should run once and when 2nd function will run on that time browser tab should not close and 2nd function website open there. i think thats the probleam, its not working :/  . how can i contact you sir ?

Comment: I don't know much about Selenium, I can't help you with that part.

Comment: No, I don't provide personal consulting like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not running like a Function Because you put  the all funtions in the list and list treated as thhses fumction like a list

Comment: loop = 10
funcs = [func1, func2, func3, func4, func5]

for i in range(10)
    print(funcs[i % len(funcs)]())